# Linear Transform $L:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ reflecting across a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $L:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, be the reflection with respect to the plane spanned by $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} -2\\-7\\ -8\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 10\\ 2\\ 7\end{bmatrix}\right\}$. Find the matrix of L. Hint: First find the matrix $[L]_{\mathbb{B}}^{\mathbb{B}}$ in a basis that contains the two given vectors and their crossed product. Then use transition matrices.

I googled how to do do use reflection matrices across a plane, but I couldn't follow why anything they were saying worked. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Instead of searching the web for formulas, why didn’t you try using the method in the hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $e,f$ be the given two vectors spanning the plane, and set $g=e\times f$ which is orthogonal to the plane. 
As the hint says, $\mathcal B:=(e, f, g)$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

By the geometric properties of the reflection, we know that
$$L(e)=e, \ \ L(f)=f, \ \ L(g)=-g$$
So the matrix of $L$ coordinated in basis $\mathcal B$ is
$$[L]_{\mathcal B}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1}$$
since this contains the $\mathcal B$-coordinates of $L(e),\, L(f),\ L(g)$ in the columns.

Then apply basis transformation:
$$[L]=B\, [L]_{\mathcal B}\, B^{-1}$$
where $B$ is the matrix with columns $e,f,g$.